# Why is it saying a isnt defined even though i have defined you

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pynput

so i defined a but when i try to type out a using keybaord.type it just says that  it isnt defined
i tried making a global that didnt work i tried moving postions of the code and that didnt work ive tried many other things they didnt work either

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
menu = Tk()
menu.geometry('200x300')

def webop(): # new window definition
    global a

    def hh():
        a = "" + txt.get()
    while True:
        keyboard = Controller()
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type(a)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)

    sp = Toplevel(menu)
    sp.title("Spammer")
    txt = Entry(sp, width=10)
    txt.grid(row=1,column=1)
    btn = Button(sp, text='spam', command=hh)
    btn.grid(row=1,column=2)





def enc():
    window = Toplevel(menu)
    window.title("nou")

button1 =Button(menu, text ="Spammer", command =webop) #command linked
button2 = Button(menu, text="Fake bot", command = enc)
button1.grid(row=1,column=2)
button2.grid(row=2,column=2)
menu.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global a` underneath `def webop()` gives `webop` access to the variable `a` in the enclosing scope (the scope up there where you're doing your imports). Since you haven't defined `a` in that scope, you're getting the error.

Either way, you generally should avoid using globals like that and pass data to functions using arguments. In order to pass arguments into your Button `command` you can use a closure.

You should move the part of your code accessing `a` to the part where that value is set

It is unclear what you're trying to achieve here since when you run `webop` your program will reach `while True` and continuously loop there and never reach the code below your while loop

For instance

```
def hh(a):
    a = "" + txt.get()
    while True:
        keyboard = Controller()
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type(a)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)

btn = Button(sp, text='spam', command=hh)
```

An alternative approach achieves the same thing using functools partial. See https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-pass-arguments-to-tkinter-button-command/

Comment: thanks worked like a charm only problem is that its a bit sluggish for some reason dont know if there a fix for that though

Comment: When you create interfaces you generally run an the interface in a separate thread than the code the interface ends up executing. Python is likely unable to to process events coming into your interface because it's busy running code in the while loop

Comment: so then is there anyway to make it so i have a kill bind